# Selecting only links in a dl - dd tag structure

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For [Fashiontrends.pk](http://www.fashiontrends.pk)    `<dl class="boccat">` holds all the links. We want write some code to find that section, and then grab all of the links within the `<dd>` elements of that section.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

BASE_URL = "http://www.fashiontrends.pk"

def get_category_links(section_url):
    html = urlopen(section_url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    boccat = soup.find("dl", "boccat")
    category_links = [BASE_URL + dd.a["href"] for dd in boccat.findAll("dd")]
    return category_links
```

Comment: Yes, and what do you need help with?

Comment: There are no DL tags in that page..

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to limit your search:

```
links = soup.select('dl.boccat dd a[href]')
```

will find only link objects with a `href` attribute, located under `dd` tags under `dl` tags with the `boccat` class.

If (some of) your URLs are relative, you want to use [`urlparse.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) here:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

def get_category_links(section_url):
    response = urlopen(section_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
    return [urljoin(BASE_URL, link["href"])
            for link in soup.select('dl.boccat dd a[href]')]
```

There is no need to call `.read()` on the response object; `BeautifulSoup()` will call it for you.

However, the specific URL you gave us has no `<dl class="boccat">` elements in the HTML served, to either a browser or to `urllib2`:

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> source = urlopen('http://www.fashiontrends.pk').read()
>>> '<dl' in source
False
```

There are no `<dl>` tags in the page, *full stop*. You didn't show us any code that would indicate what page you *are* loading.